# Clone git with submodule using github access token in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

I have a github app which invoke Jenkins pipeline every time we push new branch into github repo.
We create access token using github's `/api/v3/app/installations/${payload_installation_id}/access_tokens` url.

I am able to clone the root repository using https://x-access-toekn:/github.com just fine, but one of the repositories has submodules with ssh url.
Trying to update those submodules fails.

How can I get those submodules to clone as well using the access token?

I tried to create a `.gitconfig` with

```
[url http://x-access-toekn:token@github.com]
  insteadOf = git@github.com:
```

but that doesn't seems to work.

Comment: `[url http://x-access-toekn:token@github.com/]` <- add a slash `/` at the end so that `git@github.com:user/repo.git` is replaced with `http://x-access-toekn:token@github.com/user/repo.git`, not with `http://x-access-toekn:token@github.comuser/repo.git`

Comment: that seems to do the trick, write it as an answer I'll mark it as correct please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
git config url.http://x-access-toekn:token@github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com:
```

This changes the section to

```
[url "http://x-access-toekn:token@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
```

Please note a slash `/` at the end. The section replaces `git@github.com:user/repo.git` with correct `http://x-access-toekn:token@github.com/user/repo.git`, not with incorrect `http://x-access-toekn:token@github.comuser/repo.git` (error in `github.comuser`).